# Reactive Extensions sample for Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, reactive

How do I code with [Reactive](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET) in Xamarin.iOS in C#?

For example, I have the following code in Objective-C using [ReactiveObjC](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveObjC):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapOnSomething = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
[[tapOnSomething rac_gestureSignal] subsribeNext:^(UITapGestureRecognizer *tap) {

     // Do something here
}];
```

How does this look like in Xamarin.iOS?

Comment: refer to http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples  , http://www.introtorx.com/

Answer (score 0):

Let say I am using Tap on My Label. So you have to add the code this way

```
UITapGestureRecognizer tapLabel = new UITapGestureRecognizer(TapThat);
labelname.AddGestureRecognizer(tapLabel);
labelname.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
```

and then create method `TapThat` below way

```
void TapThat()
{
  // do whatever you want...
}
```